# PIC 16F877A interface with glcd LM12864DDY

Tags: pic, glcd

I'm using the CCS C Compiler to program my PIC 16F877A to display results of a voltage measurement. I'm using TOPWAY's LM12864DDY. I used the functions that were available in the glcd.c file in the "Examples" folder of PICC.
This is my code:

```
#include<16F877A.h>
#include"pic_GLCD.h"

#fuses HS,NOWDT,NOPROTECT
#use delay(clock=20000000) //crystal 20 Mhz
char voltText[]="VOLTS"; 

void drawFrame(x,y,w,h)
{
    int i = 0;
    glcd_rect(x, y, w, h, NO, ON);              // Outline the frame
    glcd_text57(48, 57, voltText, 1, ON);       // Display "Volts"
    for (i=5;i<=w;i+=10)                        // Draw some fancy markers :)
    {                                           // horizontal
        glcd_line(i,h,i,h+5,ON);                // every 10 pixel
    }
    for (i=y; i<=h;i+=10)                        // vertical
    {
        glcd_line(1,i,5,i,ON);
    }
} 

void main (void)
{
    //LCD PORTS
    SET_TRIS_C(0x00); 
    SET_TRIS_E(0x00);
    //CS1,CS2,RST PORT
    SET_TRIS_A(0xD3);

    glcd_init(ON);

    drawFrame(5,0,125,51);

}
```

and my output is this:
[image]

Can't really figure out what is it that I'm doing wrong. Why am I getting scattered dots in my display?

Comment: Things are basically, but not quite, in working order, suggesting you need to tweak pic_GLCD.h to match your special LCD display

Comment: It's been a while since I used CCS C, but don't you need a while(1){}; loop at the end of main()?

Comment: Hey Scott could you give me some hints? what kinds of tweaks?

Comment: I can put it in a while loop but I still get the same grainy output

Comment: No, I can't.  You'll have to look in the file and see what it says.  When these types of drivers are built, such stuff is often made clear in comments.  You should consider drivers like this as a framework for what you need to accomplish, and not gospel.

Comment: THANKS Scott!!!!! IT WORKED. Turned out my driver needed a delay cycle change !

Comment: Good Job!  Don't be afraid to go into the drivers to learn about them!